# What to do when a drive is no longer recognized under Linux?

Tags: linux, hard-drive

I was salvaging a hard drive with damaged sectors using a bash script performing calls to ddrescue. That drive was known as /dev/sdc and connected in eSata via an ExpressCard.

I could not find any way to stop my bash script, so I pressed the computer POWER button for about 10 seconds to shut it down.

I tried several times to start the computer again, but the drive is no longer recognized and does now show when doing "fdisk -l".

The boot is slow and this message is displayed after Linux tries to access the drive (I'm using SystemRescueCd):

```
udev[84]:worker [156] filed while handling '/devices-pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.2/0000:03:00.0/host2/target2:0:0/2:0:0:0/block/sdb'
```

The hard drive, itself, seems to run fine, but is not recognized.

What can I do in such case?

--- Appended 06/18/2013 ---
Here the result of lsblk:

```
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE    RO  TYPE    MOUNTPOINT
loop0   7:0 0   294.6M  1   loop    /livemnt/squashfs
sda 8:0 0   37.3G   0   disk
|_sda1  8:1 0   37.3G   0   part
sr0 11:0    1   381.2M  0   rom /livemnt/boot
sdb 8:16    0   298.1G  0   disk
```

Yes, lsblk detects the sdb drive (whilst fdisk -l didn't).

What should I do next?

Comment: run `lsblk` command in terminal and show result.

Answer (score 0):

Try under Windows. There have been times for me when Linx wouldn't detect a failing hard disk but Windows did.

Comment: I'm salvaging a Windows hard drive (formatted NTFS), which is no more recognized under Windows. That's why I'm using Linux.